# Piping output from cut

Tags: shell, scripting, debian-based

I'm trying to write a script that uses the information inside a log file that continues to grow. Every log of the file is structured like this:

"Jun 20 09:56:01 Client root: ssh-rsa ...[rsa-key]... mario@Client"

I just need the last two informations for my script, the ssh-rsa key and the username, so I've tried this:

```
tail -f /var/log/newusers | egrep --line-buffered "ssh-rsa" | cut -d' ' -f7,8
```

it was working so I added this because I needed to manipulate the information

```
| while read line ; do echo $line ; done
```

but it doesn't print anything. I'm using this as a workaround:

```
tail -f /var/log/newusers | egrep --line-buffered "ssh-rsa" | while read line ; do
    KEY=$(echo "$line" | cut -d' ' -f7)
    USER=$(echo "$line" | cut -d' ' -f8)
    echo "$USER"
done
```

but I want to understand why the first solution is not working because I think I'm missing some basic concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi your first option did not work as you have used `cut` before `while` loop because `cut` will filtered one line at a time.

```
tail -f /var/log/newusers | egrep --line-buffered "ssh-rsa" | cut -d' ' -f7,8 | while read line ; do echo $line ; done
```

In your second option you have output all the filtered lines to while loop

```
tail -f /var/log/newusers | egrep --line-buffered "ssh-rsa" | while read line ; do
```

Comment: Because it feed only one line each time to while loop not all the filtered lines. just add a counter in while loop and print it you will understand.

Comment: I still don't understand why the first solution is not working. The whole point of having a cut there is to filter every line coming and then send it to the while loop, it's the same thing for the egrep. For example if I were to do something like this:    `echo -e "a b c \na f g" | egrep "b" | cut -d' ' -f2 | while read line ; do echo "$line"; done` it will work

Comment: Just remove `cut` and see whether it work or not first.

Comment: Ok I think I finally understood what you ment. Basically piping the output from egrep sends ALL the lines filtered and cut just does send one at time, is that right? But it is like that why the while loop just doesn't print anything? Shouldn't at least print the first line sent, or maybe a buffering lag and then prints?

Answer (score 0):

awk can filter by regexp and pipe fields to `read` placing values directly into variables. `$USER` is a built-in bash variable so it's not recommended to use it in scripts unless its meaning is preserved

```
tail -f /var/log/newusers \
| gawk '{ if($0 ~ /ssh-rsa/){ print $7,$8 } }' \
| while read rsa nuser; do 
    echo "new $nuser -> rsa: $rsa"
done
```

Result:

```
new mario@Client -> rsa: ...[rsa-key]...
new mario@Client2 -> rsa: ...[rsa-key]...
new mario@Client3 -> rsa: ...[rsa-key]...
new mario@Client4 -> rsa: ...[rsa-key]...
new mario@Client5 -> rsa: ...[rsa-key]...
```